# What shouldn't I store in core data?

Tags: ios, caching, core-data, restkit

So this is more of an application design question. But I think it can be 'answered' and not just discussed. :)

I'm using RestKit for an application we're building. It obviously makes it super easy to put stuff into either straight objects or core data objects.

In the specific instance I'm dealing with, we have comments, much like comments on a facebook post.

Now, the nicest thing about storing these comments in core data is that with NSFRC I can sort them super easily and deal with updating/inserting automatically into the right spots into the timeline. But there's a couple sticking points there as well.

For instance with infinite loading, I now have to manage loading the comments in between the new most recent comments and the old stored comments. (Maybe the first time I grabbed 25, but there has been 100 new comments since then. So I retrieve the latest 25 first, then have to have an auto load cell in between the new comments and the old until I run into those, then have to paginate any after.

Aside from that, then you are also storing potentially thousands of comments in core data. Maybe it's not a big deal for quite a long time, but eventually you might want to start cleaning up old comments with a GCD task.

So what are the leading thoughts on what to store in core data, and what to keep as transient objects. (Maybe storing those in a cache like NSCache or the new Tumblr cache https://github.com/tumblr/TMCache).

### Edit

Ok maybe I should clarify a little here. I get the purpose of Core Data... for persisting across app restarts and having an object graph with relationships. I make plenty of use of it. I guess what I'm wondering about here is the grey areas where I would like things to persist for the sake of not always having to wait for a network call, and offline availability.

But much like stories and comments on facebook, there are always going to be a constant stream of new ones coming in, and you don't necessarily care about 300 comments on an old post. Someone could come back to view comments on their 'post' quite a few times, or someone may just be browsing 'posts' and comments casually, and never coming back to them.

So I'm just trying to consider the strategy for something like this where you have potentially lots of entities (comments) coming down from a service. Sometimes people will want to view them several times (their own 'post') and sometimes they are just browsing through. When trying to see how others do this, it seems some stuff it all into core data, some (like Facebook) seem to store 25-50 most recent in the db, and any beyond that are transient (they probably are clearing out older stories and comments regularly too.)

Comment: *Resists... Urge... To... Close...*

Comment: @Undo I'd say it's relevant, and could potentially be very helpful, but it will most likely end up closed.  Just my two cents: don't cache huge things, but also don't persist small things with Core Data.  As for the sync algorithms, there are entire fields of study dedicated to this stuff, so there really is neither a right answer, nor a good one, unfortunately.

Comment: @Undo Is there a more appropriate place to have this discussion with others considering the same problem?

Comment: @Bob I was referring to the first sentence.

Comment: @CodaFi I somewhat get that, but that doesn't make it clear to me. In the example of comments, they probably won't be frequently accessed, but could be worth persisting if they might be viewed several times, and core data + NSFRC makes incrementally adding more a breeze. Facebook seems to store the most recent in core data, and delete any beyond a certain number.

Answer (score 1):

Core Data is not designed to be used as "dumb data storage", but rather object persistence.  So, anything that you want to persist between uses of your app should go into Core Data.

If you are using Core Data properly, it will take care of all of your caching for you as well.

EDIT:

Anything that is going to change too often for your taste or that you just don't want to permanently store, `NSCache` may be a better option.  If you don't think your user will look at it again tomorrow, leave those bits out of your persistence. (IMHO)

Answer (score 1):

Create a scond repository. Either select a time period that is known as 'recent' or provide a preference for such. Periodically look at the primary repository and find objects now older than the recent range, and move those objects to the scond repository.

Then provide users the means to search in just recent or all.

If all they want are recent values the searches should be faster, and nothing is lost.